# Detect package-info in Java Annotation Processor

Tags: java, annotation-processing, package-info

I'm writing a Java annotation processor that creates `package-info` for packages in a Java project.

The code to actually generate the source file looks somewhat like this:

```java
JavaFileObject builderFile = filer.createSourceFile(packageName + ".package-info");

try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(builderFile.openWriter()))
{
    out.println("... file content ...");
}
```

Unfortunately, this code crashes when there already is a `package-info` for the given package, either in the source code or generated by a previous round.

Normally, I would just skip the generation if a `package-info` already exists, but I couldn't find any way to test for the existence of a `package-info`.

```java
processingEnv.getElementUtils().getPackageElement(packageName)
```

Always returns a `PackageElement`, regardless of whether there is a `package-info` or not, which seams reasonable, because the package exists with or without the `package-info`.

There also doesn't seem to be an `ElementKind` for `package-info` either and `PackageElement.getEnclosedElements()` only returns the top level classes and interfaces in that package.

In lack of a better solution, I'm currently catching and ignoring the `IOException` thrown by `Filer.createSourceFile(String)` in case the `package-info` already exists.

Is there a way to check if a certain package already contains a `package-info`?

Edit:

FWIW, the source file can be found [on Github](https://github.com/dmfs/srcless/blob/main/nullless-processors/src/main/java/org/dmfs/nullless/processors/nullless/NullLessProcessor.java#L70-L83)